# Display ajax response array values- names in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<html>

<select name="cars">
<option value="34">Volvo XC90</option>
<option value="54">Saab 95</option>
<option value="12">Mercedes SLK</option>
<option value="10">Audi TT</option>
</select>

</html>
```

I have ajax response  array like 12,54,10

now I need to display those name whose values are 12,54,10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **remove()** of a drop down object.

```
function removeOptions() {
var cars = document.getElementById("cars");
var val = [12, 54, 10];
  for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
    var isFound = false;
    for(var j=0;j<val.length; j++) {
      if(val[j] == cars[i].value) {
        isFound=true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!isFound) {
      cars[i].remove();
    }
  }
}

removeOptions();
```

You could make use of [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXzqdx).

Comment: @Chandrasekhar thanks for your answer,Instead removing permanently it is possible to hide temporary.Because on refresh i need original drop down back.

Comment: Just use `cars[i].style.display="none";` instead of `cars[i].remove();`. You could use `cars[i].style.display="block";`  for all the drop down values when you refresh. Do upvote if you found this helpful.

Comment: @ChandrasekerG...thanks ... it works for me

Comment: @Chandrasekhar...it working but last value of drop down is not removed

Comment: @ChandrasekharG...it not works when i change dropdown option second time..need to reset dropdown to original on second on change..how?